# Is this indirect const access an UB?

Tags: c++

When I was checking some code today, I noticed an old method for implementing `std::enable_shared_from_this` by keeping a `std::weak_ptr` to self in the constructor. Somthing like this:

```
struct X {
    static auto create() {
        auto ret = std::shared_ptr<X>(new X);
        ret->m_weak = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    // use m_weak.lock() to access the object
    //... 
private:
    X() {}
    std::weak_ptr<X> m_weak;
};
```

But then something came to me regarding constness of this object. Check the following code:

```
struct X {
    static auto create() {
        auto ret = std::shared_ptr<X>(new X);
        ret->m_weak = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    void indirectUpdate() const {
        m_weak.lock()->val = 1;
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    }

private:
    X() {}
    std::weak_ptr<X> m_weak;
    int val = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto x = X::create();
    x->print();
    x->indirectUpdate();
    x->print();
}
```

In this code, `indirectUpdate()` is a const method and it should not update our object, but in fact it does. Because `std::weak_ptr.lock()` returns a non-const `shared_ptr<>` even though the method is const. So you will be able to update your object indirectly in a const method. This will not happen in case of `std::enable_shared_from_this` because `shared_from_this` returns a shared pointer to **const ref** of object in const method. I wonder if this code is UB or not. I feel it should be, but I'm not sure. Any idea?

**Update:**

Sorry, it seems that my question was not relayed correctly. I meant even if we have a const pointer, we lose that constness via this method. following code shows that:

```
struct X {
    static auto create() {
        auto ret = std::shared_ptr<X>(new X);
        ret->m_weak = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    void show() const { std::cout << "const \n";}
    void show() { std::cout << "non-const\n";}

    void indirectUpdate() const {
        show();
        m_weak.lock()->show();
        m_weak.lock()->val = 1;
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    }

    int val = 0;

private:
    X() {}
    std::weak_ptr<X> m_weak;
};

int main() {
    // Here we have a const pointer
    std::shared_ptr<const X> x = X::create();
    x->print();
    x->indirectUpdate();
    x->print();
}
```

and output will be following:

```
0
const 
non-const
1
```

which shows losing constness.

Comment: the object you are modifying is not `const`.

Comment: it has no difference than outside code do `m_weak.lock()->val = 1;` (ignore private)

Comment: `const` is not transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that is modified is not `const`. There is no undefined behavior.

Add a method like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    static auto create() {
        auto ret = std::shared_ptr<X>(new X);
        ret->m_weak = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    void show() const { std::cout << "const \n";}
    void show() { std::cout << "non-const\n";}

    void indirectUpdate() const {
        m_weak.lock()->show();
        m_weak.lock()->val = 1;
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    }

private:
    X() {}
    std::weak_ptr<X> m_weak;
    int val = 0;
};

int main() {
    auto x = X::create();
    x->print();
    x->indirectUpdate();
    x->print();
}
```

To get this output:

```
0
non-const
1
```

Modifying an object via a const mehtod is ok, as long as the method only modifies an object that is actually not `const`.

It is similar to using a `const &` to a non-const object. You may cast away constness and modify it as long as the object is really not const:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    const int& ref = x;
    const_cast<int&>(ref) = 42;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

I also see no danger of misusing the pattern in your code, because once the object is `const` you won't be able to assign to its `val` member and all is fine with constcorrectness.

---

In your Update you have a `const` pointer in `main` but the object is still not `const`. Consider this simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    static foo* create(){
        auto x = new foo();
        x->self = x;
        return x;
    }

    void bar() const {
        this->self->non_const();
    }
    void non_const() {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }
    foo* self;
};

int main() {
    const foo* f = foo::create();
    f->bar();
    delete f;
}
```

Its not quite the same as yours, but it has similar effect of calling a non-const method on a seemingly `const` object. Though its all fine.

The only `foo` object is that created in `foo::create`, it is not constant. In `main` we have a `const foo*` to that object. `main` can only call the `const` member `bar`. Inside `bar` the `this` pointer is a `const foo*`, but `self` does not point to a `const foo`. `self` itself is `const, but not the object it points to.

Comment: I think I made a mistake and my question was not really relayed what I meant. The problem is that even if we have a const object pointer, we will lose constness in accessing via `weak_ptr` and I wondered if that is a UB. I updated the question to reflect that too.

Comment: @Afshin it changes not much. The output of your update shows that `this` is `const` but the object accessed via the weak pointer is not

Comment: @Afshin the only difference in your update is that in `main` you have a `const` poitner to the object. But the object itself is the same as in the old code

Comment: But when accessing `indirectUpdate()` method object was const. I don't think trying to access it via locked weak_ptr which is not const in that method will be correct. Because in that case, it makes no sense that the standard exactly written `shared_from_this()` to return const ref from a const method.

Comment: @Afshin not sure how to explain it better. See the edit. I think it is simpler to see when you drop the smart pointers. The member is a pointer to a non-const object. In a `const` method it is a const pointer to a non-const object.

Comment: @Afshin in a const method `this` refers to a const object (the current object), but that does not mean that any other reference to the current object also becomes automagically a referene to a const object.

Comment: that plus: you were only able to get a pointer to non-const `X` in the first place, because the actual object is not const.